# How to run a job on a specific time every day?

Tags: go, time

I want to print out `do my job` every day at 9pm. How can I do this in Go?

Here's what I've got so far:

```golang
timer := time.NewTimer(3 * time.Second)
for {
    now := time.Now()
    next := now.Add(time.Hour * 24)
    todayNine := time.Date(next.Year(), next.Month(), next.Day(), 9, 0, 0, 0, next.Location()).AddDate(0, 0, -1)
    todayFifteen := time.Date(next.Year(), next.Month(), next.Day(), 15, 0, 0, 0, next.Location()).AddDate(0, 0, -1)
    todayEnd := time.Date(next.Year(), next.Month(), next.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, next.Location()).AddDate(0, 0,  -1)
    if now.Before(todayNine) {
        timer.Reset(todayNine.Sub(now))
    } else if now.Before(todayFifteen) {
        timer.Reset(todayFifteen.Sub(now))
    } else if now.Before(todayEnd) {
        timer.Reset(todayEnd.Sub(now))
    }
    <- timer.C
    fmt.Println("do my job")
}
```

Comment: you can use ticker and check  hour part of  time.Now() . but would be tricky if there is mutiple instance of your service running .. you will end up each instance  doing the job once .

Comment: I would recommend using a different system outside the go binary to initiate the job. It could be a cron job or k8 cron. If you want to do it purely using go "ticker" shall be used

Comment: Your OS probably has a way of scheduling programs to run at certain times regulary as you're wanting.  What OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply as soon as possible, here is my solution, please let me know your thoughts, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would explore OS level or Infrastructure level system to trigger the execution at these times ( Cron jobs in *nix, Cron in k8s etc.)

However,  If you want to do it using purely `go` you may try using the `ticker` and `Clock` together

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
    "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Minute)
    done := make(chan bool)
    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt)
    defer stop()
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                h, m, _ := time.Now().Clock()
                if m == 0 && (  h == 9 || h == 15 ) {
                    fmt.Printf("Doing the job")
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    <-ctx.Done()
    stop()
    done <- true
}
```

Link to the [plaground](https://play.golang.org/p/jg36tvV8Z7t)

Comment: it gonna be restart ticket if you stop and re run server ? so it might not accurate using ticker for this case, i was using this for implement reminder. i prefer using crontab and make endpoint for job like this, so run a script for this to hit the endpoint, make white list ip for your vm

Comment: @Pocket as I mentioned in the answer and comment under question, an infrastructure level trigger outside the go binary would be ideal in this scenario but if they want to do it purely using go for whatever reason this is a possible solution

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply as soon as possible, here is my solution, please let me know your thoughts, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `cron` package. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron

Example from documentation:

```
c := cron.New()
c.AddFunc("0 30 * * * *", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour on the half hour") })
c.AddFunc("@hourly",      func() { fmt.Println("Every hour") })
c.AddFunc("@every 1h30m", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour thirty") })
c.Start()
..
// Funcs are invoked in their own goroutine, asynchronously.
...
// Funcs may also be added to a running Cron
c.AddFunc("@daily", func() { fmt.Println("Every day") })
..
// Inspect the cron job entries' next and previous run times.
inspect(c.Entries())
..
c.Stop()  // Stop the scheduler (does not stop any jobs already running).
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply as soon as possible, here is my solution, please let me know your thoughts, thanks!